# Can't get Application.Run to work

Tags: vba, excel

Ok I feel stupid for asking this as there are dozens of questions out there asking the same thing. But for some reason it's just not working out for me. 
I have two workbooks "Historical Data.xlsm" and "Reporting File 2.0.xlsm", and "Reporting File 2.0" is protected so I can't create any new macros within it. I want to run a macro within "Historical Data" by clicking a (assign macro) button in "Reporting File 2.0"

So I created two macros in "Historical Data", one that is the macro I want to run and a second that runs this macro, with the code:

```
Sub RunMacro()
Application.Run ("Historical Data.xlsm!ShiftRow1")
End Sub
```

But I keep getting a "Run-time error: 1004: Method 'Run' of object '_Application' failed"

If someone could direct me into the right direct that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've kinda gotten it to work, but it runs the macro in "Reporting File 2.0" where I want it to run in "Historical Data" (though triggered from "Reporting File 2.0")

Comment: Your `ShiftRow1` sub probably relies on the [ActiveSheet property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822753.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) either explicitly or by default because you offer no explicit reference to the correct worksheet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing single quotes (a must have if your workbook name has a space).

If the `ShiftRow1` is indeed in **Historical Data.xlsm**, you should do:

```
Sub RunMacro()
    Application.Run "'Historical Data.xlsm'!ShiftRow1"
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @PatricK, Feeling stupid missing such a simple thing :P